# A problem about normal extensions and automorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

this is my problem:

> Suppose $K|F$ is a normal extension. Prove that for every $\alpha ,\beta \in K$ that have the same minimal polynomial over $F$ there is a $F$-algebra automorphism of $K$ (automorphism which is identity over $F$) $\phi:K\rightarrow K$ such that $\phi(\alpha)=\beta$.

we know that if $\alpha ,\beta \in K$ have the same minimal polynomial over $F$ then $F(\alpha)\simeq_F F(\beta)$,but how can i continue?

any hint is welcomed!

thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It could be proved that there exists a $F$-*isomorphism*
$$\sigma:F(\alpha)=F[\alpha]\longrightarrow f[\beta]=F(\beta)\subseteq K$$
such that $\sigma(\alpha)=\beta$.

Now as $\bar{K}/F(\alpha)$ is *algebraic* and $\bar{K}$ is *algebraically closed* over $K$, by *Theorem 3 of Lorenz* , there is a *field monomorphism* extension $\displaystyle\tilde{\sigma}:\bar{K}\longrightarrow\bar{K}$ where $\tilde{\sigma}|_{F(\alpha)}=\sigma$.

Then, again by $F3$ of *Lorenz*, as $\tilde{\sigma}$ is an *endomorphsim & monomorphism* over $\bar{K}/F$ which is *algebraic*, hence $\tilde{\sigma}$ is an **isomorphsim** over $\bar{K}/F$.

Also by below theorem, we can infer that $\tilde{\sigma}(K)=K$.

So it suffices to define $\phi$ as follows: 
$$\phi:=\tilde{\sigma}|_{K}:K\longrightarrow K$$

---

> ***Theorem***. Let $K/F$ and $L/K$ be *normal* and *algebraic* extensions, respectively.
>   Then for every $F$*-isomorphsim* $\psi$ over $L$ :
>   $$\psi(K)=K$$

Answer (score 0):

if the minimal polynomial is $f$ perhaps one could find an $F$-isomorphism between $F(\alpha)$ and $F[X]/\langle f\rangle$ and similarly for $F(\beta)$ so that you could thereby construct an equivalence $F(\alpha) \cong F(\beta)$?

Comment: yes i know it ,but then?

Comment: would you please see this?it has bounties.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/993666/a-problem-about-normal-extensions-polynomials